# How do you calculate how many days in quarter in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

I need help calculating the following in MYSQL

how many days in quarter based on current date in MYSQL?
If today is 8/27/2014 - how many days is that in the quarter?

Also how do I calculate how many days in a quarter between two dates in MYSQL?
If user chose 3/1/2014 - 8/27/2014  how many total days for those 3 quarters?

Comment: why are you doing this in mysql? this should be done in another programming language

Comment: to get the number of days between two dates just use DATEDIFF..  `DATEDIFF(ending_date,starting_date)`

Answer (score 1):

to get the number of days in this quarter use this.

```
SELECT  
    DATEDIFF(
        MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) + INTERVAL QUARTER(CURDATE()) QUARTER - INTERVAL 1 DAY, 
        MAKEDATE(YEAR(CURDATE()), 1) + INTERVAL QUARTER(CURDATE()) QUARTER - INTERVAL 1 QUARTER 
    )
```

to get the difference between two dates just use this

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(2014-08-27','2014-03-01')
```

im not sure why you would be doing this in mysql.. there are built in functions in other languages to do this same operation. so I wouldn't recommend doing it in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for:

```
select datediff(MAKEDATE(YEAR(CurDate()), 1) 
              + INTERVAL QUARTER(CurDate()) QUARTER - INTERVAL    1 QUARTER,
                    case when Quarter(CurDate()) = quarter(curdate())    
                         then CurDate()  -- get the number of days in quarter up to today date
                         else
              -- return number of days in quarter totally
                                DATE (DATE_SUB( DATE_ADD( CONCAT( YEAR( CurDate() ), '-01-01'), 
                                INTERVAL QUARTER(CurDate()) QUARTER ), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) end) * -1   days_in_quarter
```

Comment: you didn't specify this in the question. all you said was the number of days in a particular quarter.. nothing related to the number of days up to the current day in a quarter.

Comment: This query helped me. Thank you!